# How can I export Git change sets from one repository to another via sneaker net (external files)?

Tags: git

I have a system that is installed in an area that does not have external network access and I can't bring in my computer. The system was developed with all source in a GIT repository. Since the installation there have been a few modifications mad onsite that have been committed to the systems local copy of the repository. I currently have no way to push those changes out like was done during development because of the isolation.

What I would like to do is export the 4-5 commits that have been made to an "export file(s)" that can later be used in the real world to apply the changes to the external repository such as my laptop and Bitbucket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [git bundle](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle). Create a bundle:

```
git bundle create update.bundle HEAD~5..HEAD
```

On the receiving side use `git fetch` or `git pull`:

```
git pull update.bundle master
```

Comment: For future reference, what is `HEAD~5..HEAD`? Also it possible to access the `update.bundle` file without git, just with a file explorer?

Comment: `HEAD~5..HEAD` is *an example* of a range of commits to put into the bundle. No, bundle is git-only thing.