# How do I synronize two git repos that are on different networks

Tags: git, diff, git-merge, patch, git-diff

I have a code base that is used on two different networks, A and B, that can no connectivity exists between A.git and B.git. The only way to talk between the networks is by burning a CD.

I have the git code base on both networks, but I am wondering how I can generate a patch to synchronize `A.git` and `B.git`. In other words

- I start off with `A.git` and `B.git` being exactly the same
- I work on my project on `A.git`
- I want to get my changes that are on `A.git` over to `B.git`
- What file/output could I produce on `A.git` and feed into `B.git` to make `B.git` exactly the same as `A.git`?

Please supply the commands needed to make this happen.

Comment: Can you use a memory stick to move stuff around? Then you could set up a bare repo on a stick and use it as a remote of the repos on the separate networks.

Comment: No, not an option for security reasons. I hope I wasn't voted down for that reason?

Comment: Use [`git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49101839/7976758).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either:

- [create a full bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578292/6309)
- or create an [incremental one](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle#_examples)

In both case, you would have to copy somehow only *one* file, which will then act as your remote repo (meaning, once copied over, you can pull from it)