# Move not pushed commits to the repository on another machine without remote repository

Tags: git, git-bundle

Same remote repository is cloned (up to date) on two different machines (Home and Office)
- On Home machine I have added 3 commits (Not pushed to the remote)
- Created a bundle file by `git bundle create fizz-buzz-app.bundle --all`
   `git log` for repository looks like below:

```
abcdef00012 - (HEAD -> branch-a) BRANCH-A: Display customer address
abcdef00011 - (HEAD -> branch-a) BRANCH-A: Display customer email
abcdef00010 - (HEAD -> branch-a) BRANCH-A: Display customer name
abcdef00009 - (origin/branch-a) BRANCH-A: Create view for the customer
abcdef00008 - (origin/master) Merge branch 'branch-another' into 'master'
```

On Office machine I have same repository, but without 3 commits
`git log` for repository looks like below:

```
abcdef00009 - (origin/branch-a) BRANCH-A: Create view for the customer  
abcdef00008 - (origin/master) Merge branch 'branch-another' into 'master'
```

I have copied bundle file from usb to local directory on Office machine
How I can bring "missing" commits from bundle file to already existing repository?

I know I can clone it to new repository with `git clone fizz-buzz-app.bundle`, but was wondering is there a possibility to "pull" 3 new commits from bundle file to existing repository.

Comment: I skimmed so there could be issues as bundles contain only the objects you told Git were important, but: in general, a bundle is the "data transfer" part of a `git fetch` operation against an otherwise-network-accessed remote. If you have the bundle file, you simply add it as a file-based "remote" and run `git fetch` against it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49101839/7976758