# Can we export local commits from GIT repository and import them on another system

Tags: git

As I have to push code to remote repository, but my VPN is not working(not able to push). So, is there any way to export local commits from my system's repository and import them on any other system(where VPN is working)? So that I can push my code to remote.

Comment: Make a patch (or multiple ones) and send by mail.

Comment: Or just run git daemon locally and clone the entire repository on the other machine.

Comment: @RomainValeri can you please share any good post regarding using patches in GIT.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I export Git change sets from one repository to another via sneaker net (external files)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101425/how-can-i-export-git-change-sets-from-one-repository-to-another-via-sneaker-net)

Answer (score 1):

You can, for instance, copy your repository to an USB stick and paste it on the other computer.

As long as you copy the entire repository (with its .git directory containing all information related to git) you will have exactly the same things on the new computer