# Best practices for maintaining a code base on platforms that don't talk to each other

Tags: git

I am trying to maintain a code base on several different platforms.  Because of firewalls, several of the platforms don't talk to each other.  I am trying to keep the code in a git repo.  I obviously can't make use of "git push" and "git pull".  Any advice on the best way to keep everybody's versions consistent and up to date?

Comment: Can you exchange mails? Sounds a bit "old days", also slower, but it works perfectly with bundles and mailed patches.

Comment: Or [`git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49101839/7976758) if you can copy files between the systems using an intermediate sysem.

Comment: They don't need to be able to talk to each other directly. They just need to be able to have something in common. If they're both on the internet, they could talk to any externally hosted Git tool (with a firewall exception like probably already exists for various other tools, such as email for example). If they aren't on the internet, then perhaps a hosted intranet server. If they're not on an intranet, then you're probably left with removable media.

Comment: @TTT Thanks.  I guess I should have specified, some of them will not talk to the platform I have to use to host the central repo.