# Update local repository without access to remote

Tags: git, version-control

I have two computers, one of them doesn’t have access to source repository. To keep it up to date I thought to create patch from new commits and apply it, but patches don’t keep track of commit history, only actual changes.

Is there a way to create some kind of snapshot of history so I could keep project up to date?

Comment: Check `git help bundle`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49101839/7976758 for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in comment above ‘git bundle’ fits my use case quite nicely.