# Mirroring Gitlab on disconnected networks

Tags: git, gitlab

I have 3 networks, all three networks are not connected to each other. Lets call them `network_1`, `network_2` and `network_3`.

On `network_1` I want to set up a Gitlab environment. On `network_2` and `network_3` I want to have a mirror of the Gitlab environment which is on `network_1`.

I will not push any commits to the Gitlab which will be on `network_2` and `network_3`, I will only pull from it.

Gitlab has the ability to configure repository mirroring, but this only works when the instances have connectivity between them, which I don't have in my environment.

The only ability which I have is to transfer files between the networks.

Any suggestions how I can set up mirroring (given there is no connectivity between the instances, but transfering files is possible)?

Comment: `when the instances have connectivity between them` `only ability which I have is to transfer files between the networks.` so you have connectivity or not?

Comment: @KamilCuk I can transfer files (automated), but cannot establish SSH/HTTP or other connections between them. There is a 4th network, I can put files there from network_1, and collect the files from network_2 and network_3.

Comment: To me this is less of a programming question. You maybe want to tunnel the traffic through another protocol? Check [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) for server administration questions.

Comment: @C-nan Use [git bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49101839/7976758). See also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+bundle